# Issue with snap.svg animation and zoom on android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, zooming, snap.svg

Im facing a problem when trying to make a snap.svg animation works in an android webview. The same code works in regular web browser and works also in a UIWebView in iOS. In android the animation is displayed properly,  but the webview zoom stops working ok. I can zoom but the view is continously reseted and going back to the previous zoom level. Also some artifacts appear repeating parts of the image, drawing others in a wrong place. I have tested the code in three differents android devices and its the same in all of them, so it doesnt looks like a specific device problem.

Also I have checked that just removing the animation everything works fine.

This is the code for the animation:

```
MapElement.prototype.blink = function(anim){
if (anim) {
    (function animateElement(mapelem,opacity) {
        mapelem.stop().animate({opacity: opacity}, 100, function() {
            if (opacity==0)
                animateElement(mapelem,1);
            else
                animateElement(mapelem,0);
        })
    })(this.mapEl,0);

    this.mapAnimBlink.toggle(true);
    (function animateBackground(mapelem,radius) {
        mapelem.animate({r: radius}, 1200, function() {
            mapelem.attr({r: 0});
            animateBackground(mapelem,40);
        })
    })(this.mapAnimBlink,40);
}
else{
    this.mapEl.stop();
    this.mapEl.attr({opacity:1});
    this.mapAnimBlink.stop();
    this.mapAnimBlink.toggle(false);
}
};
```

Given a list of elements id I get In a jSON string, I set the blink like this

```
function setBlinkMapElementsl(ids) {
var ids = $.parseJSON(ids);
$.each(Map.mapElements, function( index, value ) {      
    value.blink($.inArray(value.id, ids.ids)>=0);
});
}
```

Maybe the infinite loop of the animation is stressing too much the webview? Or there is a problem with snap.svg and android webviews? Any help would be appreciated